# Left 50% with margin-left negative isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to apply this exactly css in a element:

```
.element {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -285px // the element has width: 500px;
}
```

This element is inside other div with absolute position.

The browser is not applying the margin-left, and i don't know why!!!

I made a CODE PEN to help you guys help me -> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpKrmN

Thanks!

Comment: It's applying it.., but what are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: i want center the child with margin-left negative.

Comment: If it was to work correctly what would it look like ?

Comment: strange.. i change it -> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpKrmN and is working, but in my code isn't, the google chrome is commenting the line..

Comment: All fine and good to say you have a problem, but you haven't given any indication of expected results, so how are we to know what to look for? Seems to work fine in demo when uncommenting the `margin-left`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are doing, but I have a solution that might fix it. Use something like this:

```
margin-left: calc(50%-285px);
```

Comment: I have been looking into it, and it is not supported in IE 8 :( http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Answer (score 0):

Not following 100% but maybe this codepen helps:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPOQLM

Biggest change is to "block".  I converted your `p` to a `div` and made it "right" positioned.

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="interaction">
    Some text
    <br/>
    <span>Other text</span>
  </div> 
</div>
```

---

```
.main {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  top: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.interaction {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -285px;
}
```

Comment: Nothing =/. I'm seeing in my application exactly like this -> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpKrmN , but the negative margin-left exist in the css..